# How do I use R to sort rows by row ID which matches those in another dataframe?

Tags: r, sorting, duplicates

I have a dataframe where the first column is Gene ID and then each subsequent column are numerical values showing gene expression level (TP1, TP2 ...TPn). I would like to pick out only rows which match a second list of genes and create an output dataframe with only that data. Below is an example of what my input and output data would look like.

Dataframe1

| Gene ID | TP1 | TP2 | ...TPn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene_1 | 121 | 243 | 415 |
| Gene_2 | 45 | 23 | 52 |
| Gene_3 | 284 | 392 | 482 |
| Gene_4 | 83 | 72 | 90 |

Dataframe2

| Gene ID |
| --- |
| Gene_1 |
| Gene_3 |

Dataframe_Output

| Gene ID | TP1 | TP2 | ...TPn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene_1 | 121 | 243 | 415 |
| Gene_3 | 284 | 392 | 482 |

Comment: You can use `subset(Dataframe1, GeneID %in% Dataframe2$GeneID)`.  If there is space in column name, wrap with backquotes around the column name

Comment: Or `dplyr::left_join(Dataframe2, Dataframe1)`